# Bootstrap date picker showing different dates on input and pop up calendar

Tags: jquery, vue.js, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker and in a modal.

```
              <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header Modal">
                <button type="button" class="close" @click="cancel()" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:white;">&times;</button>
                <p>This is a header</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modalContent">
                <p>TSome random text</p>
                <p><b>Effective Date:</b></p>
                <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="width:200px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="effectivedate" value="01/01/2000">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" style="color:#2e6da4;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modalFooter">
                <button class="btn-primary" style="border-width:0px!important;" @click="save()" data-dismiss="modal">Save Update</button>
                <button class="btn-secondary" @click="cancel()" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';     

export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    computed: mapState({
        AlertPageHeader: state => state.AlertPageHeader,
        CurrentTableID: state => state.CurrentTableID,
        CurrentAlertID: state => state.CurrentAlertID
    }),

    methods: {
        save: function () {
            UpdatePatientTypeIndicator(this.CurrentTableID, this.CurrentAlertID, document.getElementById("effectivedate").value);
            document.getElementById("effectivedate").value = "01/01/2010";
        },
        cancel: function () {
            document.getElementById("effectivedate").value = "01/01/2010";

        },

    }
}
```

Date picker is defaulted to a value and it shows fine with the initial load. Issue is after the user selects any random date and cancels/saves it, and opens the modal again. input field shows the defaulted date but the calendar shows precious selected date.

[image: Like this]

I am new to all this.

Comment: In your `save` method, try removing the `document.getElementById("effectivedate").value = "01/01/2010";`

Comment: I want 01/01/2010 to be a defaulted date, that works fine. but my calendar pop up shows previous selected date as shown in my question.